# Zend Framework Xml DomDocument

Tags: xml, zend-framework, domdocument

I have problem with xml DomDucument -> using url of xml file, in Zend Framework.

When i use a fixed written url then works.

Exam.

```
$path = "http://www.wtatennis.com/dynamicxml/tennis/12781/players/player/13179/rank_history.xml";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($path);
.
.
.
```

But when i try to get xml from post url then doesn't work

Exam

```
$xml = $this->_request->getPost('xml'); //here i get url from form
$path = $xml;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($path);
.
.
.
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that your server restricts the [HTTP fopen wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) by disabling [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

This would be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: if i put this code just in simple php file exam. test.php and put it on same server then works, but when i want to use in controller then give me empty array.

Comment: @user My concern was with those two warning messages. If you're going to use a `var_dump()` in a controller action, you might as well `exit;` right after. ZF uses output buffering so you probably won't see your dumps

Comment: but if i put var_dump to comment and try to add content to database. it's stil given empty array